# Exception in logs after datastax-enterprise cassandra Upgrade

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have recently upgraded datastax-enterprise from 4.8.16 to 5.0.15. After the upgrade I see below exception in logs, although the Cassandra queries are running fine.

```
INFO   [epollEventLoopGroup-6-10 - org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message:627] Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x9b377ba1, L:/10.26.156.233:9042 ! R:/10.26.143.14:43788]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(...)(Unknown Source)
2018-12-11 09:35:42.478 INFO   [epollEventLoopGroup-6-10 - org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message:627] Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x9b377ba1, L:/10.26.156.233:9042 ! R:/10.26.143.14:43788]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
```

Comment: it's very hard to say without additional information. It could be incompatible client, for example, or something else. Why you don't raise a support ticket?

Comment: Yes, thought of checking this in stackoverflow first, else will raise a support ticket.

Comment: it's really require more information - what versions of drivers clients use, etc. For example, if you're Java clients use version 2 of drivers, then they won't work with DSE 5.0 because it requires driver 3.x: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/native_protocol/

Comment: @Alex : I using Java Clients version 3.3.2 which is compatible with DSE 5. This seems to be netty issue but not sure what it is trying to indicate.

Comment: I'm also can't remember out of the head...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. As DSE Cassandra 5.0 doesn't support Thrift protocol, and some of the application (dont ask me why, some very old applications) using Thrift protocol to connect with Upgraded cassandra causing this error.